# Emulate tee with cat + redirections

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm learning bash redirections and wonder if there a way to emulate tee command with cat using redirections. Is that possible? Or may be there are some other ways to do this.

---

Before asking about tee I just sought for a possibility to split one streem into two identical ones using bash expression. But it seems to be impossible.

Comment: Not so far as I know with `cat`; you would I believe have to write your own tool that reads from standard input and writes simultaneously to standard output and to a specified list of files.  But then you will end up with a roll-your-own implementation of `tee`.

Comment: You can in zsh with the `MULTIOS` option set, but I don't think you can hack it into bash.

Answer (score 5):

Provided that the Here is a bash function with the same functionality as `tee` and `tee -a`, provided the file does not contain `¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤!` (you can adjust this string to your liking, to make it highly unlikely that a file will ever contain it):

```bsh
tee(){
  [ "$1" = '-a' ] && shift || rm -f "$1"
  sed 's/\x0/¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤!/g' - | while read line; do
    echo "$line" | sed 's/¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤!/\x0/g' >> "$1"
  done
}
```

Tested with bash and zsh.

Example use:

```
echo asdf | tee -a file
```

Comment: @roaima, +1, and see also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803). Using `</dev/stdin` is also wrong, especially on Linux.

Comment: Without `-a`, the `tee` command truncates and overwrites the destination rather than removing it. (You lose permissions, ownerships, etc. if you `rm`.) I'd change `rm -f "$1"` to a simple `>"$1"`

Comment: This script removes spaces following a newline character. It also doesn't handle `tee file1 file2 file3...` nor does it copy its _stdin_ to _stdout_.

Comment: Alexander, I declined your flag to remove Stéphane's comment, as I think there's still value in using `printf` over `echo` when dealing with arbitrary data like we are here. There's also good advice in there about the `while read` construct.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it in bash with redirections, but you can do something like this:

```
$ cat file1
europe|EU
australia|AU
china|CN

$ cat file1 | { IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a a; printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"; printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" >teetest; }
europe|EU
australia|AU
china|CN

$ cat teetest
europe|EU
australia|AU
china|CN
```

Alternative:

```
$ { IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a a; printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"; printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" >teetest; } <file1
```

Or you can built a function:

```
$ function teetest { v="$(</dev/stdin)";printf '%s\n' "$v";printf '%s\n' "$v">teetest; }

$ cat file1 |teetest
europe|EU
australia|AU
china|CN

$ cat teetest
europe|EU
australia|AU
china|CN
```

Comment: These work only for text files. Specifically, character 0 (NULL) will not be copied

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, yes, not with `bash`.

With `zsh`:

```
cat file.in > file1.out > file2.out
```

or even:

```
< file.in > file1.out > file2.out
```

or with brace expansion to generate the output files:

```
< file.in > file{1..2}.out
```

(running `$NULLCMD`: `cat` by default)

Note that `cat` has only one stdout which it writes the content of `file.in` to. Above, `cat`'s stdout is a pipe. And `zsh` reads that output from the other end to write it to both `file1.out` and `file2.out`.

In other words, there's no magic there, `zsh` is just implementing `tee` internally.

Comment: Thank you, Stéphane, for information about zsh. I'm studying redirections using your valuable examples and tutorials.